# Participating in RANDAO

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, randomness, protocol

Can people participate in RANDAO and earn some extra bucks along the way?
According to [RANDAO github](https://github.com/randao/randao), it seems possible:

> The RNG cycle is very short, and could be for example 20 cycles in one hour, if one cycle's profit is 0.001% , the monthly rate of return is up to 0.00001 * 20 * 24 * 30 = 0.144. Targeting to 14.4% monthly rate of return, and RNG has n participants on average, the running costs of contract is n * 3 * 500 * gasPrice + Ccost

But I have no way of finding an instruction or any other material on actually participating in RANDAO.

Please let me know if it's possible, or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at these resources to attempt to participate in RANDAO. This includes how to generate a random number for the next episode as well as the suggested code:

https://medium.com/@tokenville_tv/randao-is-launched-for-episode-1-fc0dea39ebc9

https://replit.com/@deuseth/RandaoParticipate